# Matrix determinant calculator for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

So I'm trying to make a determinant calculator and found the algorithm for it. I had to change it a bit in order to accommodate swift.

I want to find the determinant of a matrix which is 6x7 but the last column would not be included in the calculation. (ie. calculating a 6x6 matrix)

Im getting this error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Can anyone explain what this means?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var values = [Double]()

    @IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

        for case let textField as UITextField in self.view.subviews {
            if textField.text == "" {
                textField.text = "0"

            }

            values.append(Double(textField.text!)!)
        }

        print(values)

        // convert to 2d
        var matrix = [[Double]]()
        matrix = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]


        for var i = 0 ; i<6;i++ {
            for var j = 0 ; j<7 ; j++ {
                matrix[i][j] = values[i*7 + j]


            }
        }


        print(matrix)

        var n = 6

        determ(matrix, n: 6)
    }

    func determ (matrix: [[Double]], var n:Int) -> Double {
        var det:Double = 0
        var p:Int, i:Int, j:Int,k:Int, h:Int
        var temp: [[Double]] = []
        for p = 0; p < n; p++ {
            h = 0
            k = 0

            for i = 1; i < n ; i++ {
                for j = 0; j < n; j++ {
                    if (j == p) {
                        continue
                    }
                    temp[h][k] = matrix[i][j]
                    k++
                    if k == (n-1) {
                        h++
                        k = 0
                    }

                }
            }
            var power = Double(p)
            var neg = Double(-1)
            det = Double(det + matrix[0][p]) * pow(neg, power) * Double(determ(temp, n: n-1))

        }
        return det
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? What exactly is wrong in your code, specify lines or so please.

Comment: the error is for line   
temp[h][k] = matrix[i][j]

and the console says "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `func determ()`, exactly this line:

`var temp: [[Double]] = []`

You are creating an empty array. Then in the loop you are setting the values in the indexes way beyond the array indexes (in fact, array doesn't have ANY indexes).

`temp[h][k] = matrix[i][j]`

You need to fill the array with 0's or whatever other way you find (maybe appending), because you can't set the values e.g. for `temp[2][3]` with empty `temp`.

Comment: thank you! it worked without error. I keep getting the determinant = -0 so I'm assuming the algorithm is incorrect

Comment: Yea, i would go step by step debugging session to see where the values are not the expected ones. Also, if it helped, please mark it as accepted. You might want also to read this (since you are new): http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers